# TypeError dispatcher.useState is not a function when using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

as I want to try out the new [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) proposal by installing `react@16.8.1` in my `package.json`, but I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: dispatcher.useState is not a function

  2 | import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
  3 | 
  4 | function App() {
> 5 |   const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    |                                     ^
  6 |   useEffect(() => {
  7 |     document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  8 |   });
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

There could be many reasons, and most are due to version incompatibilites or using a `^` in `package.json`:

### 1. Ensure `react` and `react-dom` are of the same version

Ensure that you have also updated the `react-dom` package and it is **of the same version as `react`**. In general `react` and `react-dom` should always be the same version in `package.json` as the React team updates them together.

**If you want to install React `16.7.0-alpha.2`, check that you are not using the `^` as you will install 16.7 instead, which doesn't have hooks.**

Example `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.4", // Make sure version is same as react-dom
    "react-dom": "16.8.4",
    ...
  }
}
```

---

### 2. `react-test-renderer` is of the same version as `react` and `react-dom`

If you are using Jest, ensure that `react-test-renderer` is of the same version as `react` and `react-dom`:

Example `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "16.8.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.4",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `Also check that you are not using the ^ as you will install 16.7 instead, which doesn't have hooks.` Much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm getting this even with 16.8.1 and a NPM force install.

Comment: @YangshunTay https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54608532/error-when-using-usestate-in-official-example

Comment: No, still it didn't worked ! Can you give us the fiddler where you did the same and it worked for you?

Comment: Thank you. I had added `"^"` for the react version. Removing it could solve this issue.

Answer (score 9):

You may get same error when using jest. So to fix the error I had to update react-test-renderer to have the same version as react and react-dom

```
yarn add -D react-test-renderer@next
```

Or

```
npm i react-test-renderer@next
```

All react, react-dom and react-test-renderer should contain same version

```
"react": "^16.7.0-alpha.0",
"react-dom": "^16.7.0-alpha.0",
"react-test-renderer": "^16.7.0-alpha.0"
```

Answer (score 9):

Fixed mine by calling `React.useState(0)`.

If a react version is new enough, it just has to use `React.useState`.

Comment: Thanks for this! Because of your answer, I rechecked the line where I called { useEffect, useState }. Weird but the module 'react' got updated to 'react-redux'.

Answer (score 6):

Now that react 16.7 (the one **not** containing hooks) is released you might get an error if you type `^16.7.0-alpha.0` with the leading `^` in your `package.json`.

For the version with hooks you have to omit the `^`.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are using the hook correctly. it also works for me when you use it wrong but the error description is not enough.

```
 import React,{useState} from 'react';

 const ComponentName= () => {
   const[stateOne, setStateOne]= useState(initial); // right usage - []
   const{stateTwo, setStateTwo}= useState(initial); // wrong usage - {}
                                                                     
   useEffect(() => {
       setStateOne(value1);
       setStateTwo(value2);
   }, []);
}

export default ComponentName;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did wrong -- I accidentally put curly braces instead of square brackets. Thanks @hknzbyn.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated to the latest version of react and react DOM, it works for me.
[Check React versions here](https://reactjs.org/versions/)

Answer (score 1):

the same error occurred to me.

My mistake was:
I used :

```
import {useState} from 'react/cjs/react.development'
```

you should use:

```
import {useState} from 'react'
```

Answer (score 0):

if [yangshun-tay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1751946/yangshun-tay) does not satisfy your case and you are using submodule or child module, just use `npm dedupe` this command will look to existing `package.json` start with your parent to child into leap child and merge all duplicated modules and put it into root `node_modules` same level directory with your parent `package.json`.

here is the reference for [npm-dedupe](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-dedupe)

Answer (score -3):

Use React and `{useState}`:

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';

const Renu = () => {
    const[heart,heartSet]= useState('renu'); 
    return(
        <h1>vikas love {heart}</h1>
    )
}

export default Renu;
```