# "Cannot import useState because there is no useState export in react" (Flow with React Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, react-hooks

I hope I'm not repeating a question. I've seen this one: [TypeError dispatcher.useState is not a function when using React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024307/typeerror-dispatcher-usestate-is-not-a-function-when-using-react-hooks), however my App runs fine, it is only an error in Flow:

```
Cannot import `useState` because there is no `useState` export in `react`.

   4| import { useState } from 'react';
```

I am using `16.7.0-alpha` for my react and react-dom dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    ...
    "react": "^16.7.0-alpha",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0-alpha"
  },
```

This is the only error I get from Flow, other React elements are fine. Is there something wrong with my dependencies?

This is the top of my file:

```
// @flow

import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
```

**Edit:** I also went into my node_modules/react folder and verified that the `useState` function is indeed in there.

Comment: React typings still not updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update Nov 11 2018** - Brian Vaughn from the React team has added Flow types for React hooks and it has been merged - https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/7149/

The React Flow types are not yet updated as seen [here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/react.js).

You could make a PR to update it if you are up for it (:

Comment: Haha a bit above my paygrade I think. Thanks!

Comment: It appears that as of Nov 13 2018, hooks have been added to the React Flow Types, but I'm still getting the type error in flow 0.89.0 (I guess it's coming soon)

Comment: I tried to update react in "flow-typed", but it complains anyway. How to apply new react flow-types to the project?

Comment: I'm still facing this issue, did someone get a solution?

Answer (score 1):

After searching everywhere Found the Solution Use Flow as mentioned by many developers above I tried installing flow and it works

**`npm i -D flow-babel-webpack-plugin`** works for me, but

Also If that not work try once this also
`"flow-bin": ">=0.44.2 <1",`