# React 16.7 Hooks : `react.useState` is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying functional components with hooks of react 16.7,there is an error:

[image]

src/components/Footer/index.js

```
function Footer() {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState('redTab');
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);
  const [fullScreen, setFullScreen] = useState(false);
 //...
}
```

package.json

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure you have installed it and not just bumped the version in `package.json`? Try to remove `node_modules` and install again: `rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install`. Make sure you upgrade `react-dom` to the same version as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError dispatcher.useState is not a function when using React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024307/typeerror-dispatcher-usestate-is-not-a-function-when-using-react-hooks)

Comment: in my case, I need use `[]` isntead of `{}` to get the variable & set function.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make sure that you upgrade `react-dom` to `16.7.0-alpha.0` as well.

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.7.0-alpha.0",
    "react-dom" :"16.7.0-alpha.0",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

It might also be that you only bumped the version in `package.json` without installing the new version. [You can remove `node_modules` and install again](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci).

```
npm ci
```

**Example**

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Footer() {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState('redTab');
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);
  const [fullScreen, setFullScreen] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setSelectedTab('blueTab')}>{selectedTab}</button>
      <button onClick={() => setHidden(isHidden => !isHidden)}>
        {hidden ? 'hidden' : 'visible'}
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setFullScreen(isFullScreen => !isFullScreen)}>
        {fullScreen ? 'fullscreen' : 'windowed'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Footer />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: If you're here from the future, make sure you have at least React v16.8 also don't forget to update your `react-dom` dependency as well. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 3):

I have installed both react and react-dom alpha, as you can [see in this package.json](https://github.com/WebReflection/clickblaster/blob/master/react-hooks/package.json).

Using, in the same project, the following code, would work just fine:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [icount, setICount] = useState(0);
  const {current: increment} = useRef(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5));
  return (
    <div>
      Count {count}<br />
      Increment {increment}<br />
      <button onClick={() => {
        setCount(count + 1);
        setICount(icount + increment);
      }} clicks={count}>
        Current {icount}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Counter;
```

That export can be tested/used via a basic app like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Counter from './Counter';

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.body);
```

I hope this example clarifies/solves your issues.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

React and react-dom versions are different in your package.json

So to fix the issue you need to upgrade react-dom to the same version as react

Run below command. This will install react-dom version 16.7.0-alpha.0

```
 npm i -s react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0
```

After installing react-dom re bundle the project.