# Errors while using React Hooks with Electron JS and react-data-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, react-hooks, react-data-grid

I am trying to integrate react data grid with electron js and I am facing issues while using "useState". The console asks me to add error boundaries and adding that didn't help too. I searched for similar problems in stackoverflow and made sure that the react is upgraded to the latest version for using hooks and is same with react-dom. But even after following the above steps I cannot make this work.

I am trying to follow Advanced Filtering option from the react-data-grid documentation http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/docs/examples/advanced-filtering

But the only difference is I am trying to use react-data-grid on electron js. Since I'm new to javascript, I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Repository link: https://github.com/shreyamdg/ReactDataGrid/tree/error-boundaries

Screenshot of the error:

[useState error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unIlL.png)

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Comment: Refer back to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53282848/react-16-7-hooks-react-usestate-is-not-a-function) and see if it has any correlation with yours.

Comment: Probably you aren't using the latest  alpha version yourself or the library doesn't support it yet.Either way, unless you provide a code its hard to figure out

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is uncompatable for a while .

I just import useState, din't do anything else,still has problem.

just wait

```

const App=()=>{
      const [size,setSize]=useState(""); //just add this statement,make comment,is good
    return (

```

Comment: Sorry but this is kind of a comment not an answer