# Image map library is working with React but fails on Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, canvas, next.js

I have a project for a client which requires me to use an image map.
Searching for a good library, I was barely able to find anything maintainable. The best I found was this library.

https://github.com/img-mapper/react-img-mapper

For some reason though, it works just fine with React, but fails on Next.js - it simply doesn't render.
Here's how it looks (I've added a yellow container around it to see where it should be) - https://imgtr.ee/image/WqlTX

I've tried to open a Sandbox to add to the issue I've reported, but the library makes it fail (something to do with the useState). I thought maybe it's because it tries to render it as a server component, so added `"use client"` to the component in which I render the image map but still nothing.

Here are the two Sandboxes:

Next.js - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/brave-bush-snhmy6
React - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/staging-sun-sfqczd

I've looked at the library's code, and it's not too complicated (in terms of working parts and components. I don't have much experience working with canvas) so I tried to just copy the entire code localy to my project and change what I can.

I've added `"use client`" to the image map component itself, and also replaced the `img` tag with next/image `Image` tag. Still nothing shows up (using constant values for height and width to try and narrow down what the issue might be).
Any help here would be appreciated (would gladly take a reference for a different working library as well).

```
  return (
    <div ref={container} id="img-mapper" style={styles(props).container}>
      <Image
        ref={img}
        role="presentation"
        // className="img-mapper-img h-96 w-64"
        style={{
          ...styles(props).img,
          ...(!imgRef ? { display: "none" } : {}),
          height: 640,
          width: 480,
        }}
        src={srcProp}
        useMap={`#${map.name}`}
        alt="map"
        onClick={(event) => imageClick(event, props)}
        onMouseMove={(event) => imageMouseMove(event, props)}
        height={640}
        width={480}
      />
      <canvas
        ref={canvas}
        className="img-mapper-canvas"
        style={styles().canvas}
      />
      <map className="img-mapper-map" name={map.name} style={styles().map}>
        {isRendered && !disabled && imgRef && renderAreas()}
      </map>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I see some solution for your problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53282848/react-16-7-hooks-react-usestate-is-not-a-function in case if it make sense or help to solve the problem.

Comment: @RupalJaviya appreciate your answer. It seemed to be an issue with SandBox maybe? 'm not sure. I've started a new repo in SandBox and then it was working fine. Not sure why the inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

@Tsabary

I fixed your project on Codesanbox, I just updated the next version to "13.5.4" it worked
only show and error about the defaultProps but the owner of that should fix it
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/brave-bush-snhmy6