# Why am I getting "TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.useState is not a function" error when using reactjs hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-hooks

I'm trying to use this component straight from the Material Ui (Simple Menu https://material-ui.com/demos/menus/#menus) docs in order to make a menu appear.  However, I'm getting `TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.useState is not a function` error with my current attempt below.  I tried:

- `import React, { useState } from 'react';` and then got rid of `React` inside `const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);` to make it look like: `const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);`
- I also tried replacing `null` with a number but still got same error.

Note: Another attempt installed the right packages and made my `package.json` file look like this ([TypeError dispatcher.useState is not a function when using React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024307/typeerror-dispatcher-usestate-is-not-a-function-when-using-react-hooks)):

```
{
  "name": "speedy-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.7.0-alpha.0",
    "react-dom": "16.7.0-alpha.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.7.0-alpha.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Screen shot of error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

const SimpleMenu = () => {
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

    function handleClick(event) {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    }

    function handleClose() {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button
                aria-owns={anchorEl ? 'simple-menu' : undefined}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={handleClick}
            >
                Open Menu
            </Button>
            <Menu id="simple-menu" anchorEl={anchorEl} open={Boolean(anchorEl)} onClose={handleClose}>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SimpleMenu;
```

Comment: Use the latest react's alpha version

Comment: @Oscar how would I ensure that?

Comment: `npm i --save react@next react-dom@next` should do it :)

Comment: @Oscar yeah I tried that, but now I'm getting TypeError: `Cannot set property 'current' of undefined`.

Comment: can you show a line to which this error points to? I don't see any `current` property at the code you provided

Comment: @Oscar I added a screenshot  of the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186873/discussion-between-greyskies-and-oscar).

Comment: What was the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not sure what is wrong in the code above (my guess is using a non-release build of material-ui in which an export was not default as it documentation states), this error occurred for me with improper imports. My issue was that I was trying to

```
import someNonDefaultFunction from 'someModule';
```

Adding the braces around the named/non-default import resolved the same error message for me:

```
import {someNonDefaultFunction} from 'someModule';
```