# Error when using useState in official example

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This code came from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

```
import React from 'react';
import useState from 'react'

let f = function() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default f;
```

Firstly, this line from that page...

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

... results in `useState` being null, but I changed that line. Anyhow, I get the following error...

```
TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...) is not a function
```

This error goes way if I change the code to this...

```
const [count, setCount] = [1, () => {}]
```

So I figure `useState` is the problem - it's not a function. Perhaps my custom import is not doing the correct thing. In which case, why doesn't the official import work?

I'm using React 16.8.1. My packages file has these...

```
"react-dom": "16.8.1",
"react": "16.8.1",
```

I've delete the local `node_modules` folder and run `npm install --force -g`.

`Console.log` on `useState` gives...

[image]

Comment: This is super odd. Could you use a codesandbox link or post your repo?

Comment: Don't think so. I can delete the local node_modules and it still works.

Comment: oh, you have to restart the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to restart the web server to recompile with a new version of React. Doh.

Answer (score 3):

`useState` is a named export. You cannot import it like a default export.

Change these two lines

```
import React from 'react';
import useState from 'react';
```

to

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

Comment: I  mentioned this in the question. That results in useState being undefined.

Comment: Could you perhaps try deleting your `package-lock.json` and run `npm i` instead of `npm install --force -g`?

Comment: Also, did you use `create-react-app` to create the project?

Comment: Yes I used create-react-app. Unfortunately deleting the lock file didn't work.

Comment: Actually, I didn’t use create-React-app with the version that supports hooks. I’m upgrading an existing app. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Ideally, it shouldn't. Just upgrading your react and react-dom packages should get things to work.