# React 16.13.1 Hooks error `React.useState is not a function`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-dom

I've got this error

```
ERROR    TypeError: React.useState is not a function. (In 'React.useState(false)', 'React.useState' is undefined)
```

I'm using these dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.3",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.6.2",
    ...
  }
```

I thought [Hooks are available](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) from 16.8.0 and above. Isn't it? What's the problem?

**EDIT**

Here the snipper of code that causes the crash

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import * as React from 'react';

export default function useCachedResources() {
  const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = React.useState(false);

  // Load any resources or data that we need prior to rendering the app
  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function loadResourcesAndDataAsync() {
      try {
        SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

        // Load fonts
        await Font.loadAsync({
          ...Ionicons.font,
          'space-mono': require('../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
        });
      } catch (e) {
        // We might want to provide this error information to an error reporting service
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        setLoadingComplete(true);
        SplashScreen.hideAsync();
      }
    }

    loadResourcesAndDataAsync();
  }, []);

  return isLoadingComplete;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the line of code that is causing the problem as well as your import statements?

Comment: Are you including React via `import React from 'react'` or `import * as React from 'react'`?

Comment: what's your `react-test-renderer` version?

Comment: @Z.Fralish edited and added the snippet of code

Comment: @Ryan with `import * as React from 'react';`

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani `"react-test-renderer": "~16.13.1",`

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = useState(false);
```

Comment: seems better but I got `TypeError: (0, _react.useState) is not a function` error. Here detailed: [link](https://imgur.com/2727911)

Comment: See if anything from this post helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024307/typeerror-dispatcher-usestate-is-not-a-function-when-using-react-hooks